# A problem when I set height/width of the body

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a normal HTML page and I've set the height/width of the body With `Vh` and `Vw`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Top-banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Ad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Ad .Close-but {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

.Main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="Top-banner">


</div>

<div class="Ad">
  <button class="Close-but">Close</button>

</div>

<div class="Main-content">


</div>
```

The problem is that an extra content create on the left its the body what am I doing wrong 
I cannot put an jsfiddle demo because in the demo this problem don't happen I tried the HTML page in other computers and the same issue

Comment: Add the css rule `position: relative` to the body element, and the rule `box-sizing: border-box;` to the all elements selector `*` to prevent overflows, since you are taking the whole space, so there is no space for padding or borders, so they overflow the 100% width, but setting the box sizing to border box prevents that, and instead they take inner space of the element

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand your question correctly but if your problem is the horizontal scrollbar then simply change 'overflow: auto;' to 'overflow-x: hidden;'
if you don't want a vertical scroll aswell then make 'overflow: hidden;'

```
body{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: red;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden; //change this
 }
```